# How do I merge all the outputs from for loop into single json using jq

Tags: json, bash, jq

How do I merge all the json outputs from if and elif into single json using jq.

Bash script to generate multiple jsons:

````
for i in "${arr1[@]}"
do
    ```commands```

    if [ condition ]; then
        ``json_values``

    elif [ condition ]; then
        ``json_values``
    fi
done
````

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I used other way to solve the issue. updated there

Comment: so, if that doesn't solve my problem, I need to mark as solved? @Inian

Comment: why removed your comment @Inian

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mre]; something we can copy-paste and work on.

Comment: @user47: I'll leave it to your judgement! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pipe into `jq -s .`:

```
for .... ; do ... ; done | jq -s .
```